# Why doesn't my viewDidLoad function behave the same way the 2nd time it is run?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This question is a bit hard to describe but, my problem is that when my app first loads, the viewDidLoad() function for my main view controller works and runs as intended. However, if I transition to my other view controller and then proceed to dismiss that view controller and load the main one again, the viewDidLoad() function runs again, but does not behave the same.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**MainViewController:**

This method is used to transition to the other view controller

```
    @IBAction func settingsButtonPressed() {
        dismiss(animated:false, completion: nil)
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settings")
        vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc!,animated: true)
    }
```

This is the main vc's viewDidLoad method

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        print("VIEW DID LOAD")
        
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        writeTextView.delegate = self
        
        pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
        pickerView.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

        // setup gesture recognizers
        let settingsTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        
        let infoTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        
        infoButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        infoButton.addGestureRecognizer(infoTapGestureRecognizer)
        settingsButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        settingsButton.addGestureRecognizer(settingsTapGestureRecognizer)
    
        /*
         STYLING
        */
        pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100)
        pickerView.center = self.view.center
        //pickerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        //pickerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        rotationAngle = -90 * (.pi/180)
        pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
    }
```

**SettingsViewController:**

This method dismisses the settings vc and presents the main vc

```
    @IBAction func exitButtonPressed() {
        
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
        
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main")
        vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc!,animated: true)
    }
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

The main thing to note here is that in the main view controller's viewDidLoad method, I am reloading all of the picker views components, and I am selecting row 1:

```
    pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
    pickerView.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

When I open the app, the picker view is on row 1 as I intended because of the selectRow method seen above. However if I scroll to row 0 on the picker view, open the settings view controller, then dismiss the settings view controller with the exitButtonPressed() method and bring the main vc back, the viewDidLoad method runs (I know this because "VIEW DID LOAD" prints when I do this), however, the picker view has not moved and is still on row 0 where I left it. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here.

Comment: Why don't you find out the purpose of `viewDidLoad` before you use it?

Comment: @ElTomato setup after loading the view? I wouldn't doubt that I'm not using it correctly but could you elaborate.

Comment: You shouldn't be instantiating a new "main" view controller after dismissing the settings view controller. Just dismiss it, and your main view controller will be there as you left it.

Comment: @MikeTaverne ah okay makes sense. And then after that, the whole reason why I'm running into this issue is I'm trying to reload the main vc's pickerView from my settings vc, but I couldn't figure out a way to do this other than using the viewDidLoad() method. I have tried doing MainViewController().pickerView.reloadAllComponents() in the exitButtonPressed() method but that doesn't work because pickerView's value is nil while I'm in the settings vc. Any ideas?

Comment: You use `viewDidLoad` to set up the UI of the view controller once and for all.  You should know the difference between `viewDidLoad` and other life cycle guys.

Comment: @EthanM If you are trying to update your main view controller based on a value that is selected in your settings view controller, then you need some way to pass that value back. It's a very bad practice to have your settings view controller manipulate your main view controller's picker view. You might instead have your main view controller pass a settings object to the settings view controller and have the settings view controller update it. Or use UserDefaults to share information between the view controllers.

Comment: [Delegation](https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/) is a common pattern used to pass data back

Comment: @MikeTaverne Sorry I should've said I am using user defaults. The main vc picker view and the settings vc picker view get their data from UserDefaults.stringArray(forKey: "algorithms"). The flow of what I am trying to do is: 1. Open settings vc 2. update the UserDefaults stringArray "algorithms" 3. dismiss the settings vc and have the main vc's pickerView update with pickerView.reloadAllComponents().

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you! In this case I am using user defaults, and I don't actually have to pass any data, I just need to reloadAllComponents() for a picker view in my MainViewController from my SettingsViewController

Comment: Then you can use `viewWillAppear`